# To insert lists into rows at a particular index position and update index pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, insert-update

I have a dataframe and two list `newx newy`. So I want to insert this two list at a particular index position.
my dataframe looks like below , the 1st column represents index
My two list are

```
newx = [492, 491]
newy = [260, 247]
```

[image]

I want to insert at index 595 and 596 in column1 the `newx` list and column2 the `newy` list and update the remaining index
So my output dataframe should look like

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
# df is the big existing dataframe
# splitting dataframe by row index 
df_1 = df.iloc[:594,:].reset_index() 
df_3 = df.iloc[595:,:].reset_index()

df_2 = pd.DataFrame({'newx' :[492, 491], 'newy' : [260, 247]})

frames = [df_1, df_2, df_3]

result = pd.concat(frames)
```

So break the data frame into two parts were you want to insert, then make the section you want to insert.  Then join them back up.